# function with several variables $C^1$ on the open unit ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider $\Omega$ is the open ball centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $R$ in $R^2$. I would like to show that the function $f : \overline{\Omega}\mapsto R$ is $C^1(\Omega)$ but not $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$. I don't know how to deal with this : 
$$f(x,y)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$$

Comment: Showing $C^1(\Omega)$ is standard. What goes wrong at boundary points? (First of all, what is the definition for being $C^1$ at a boundary point?) Is $f(x) = \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ going to be $C^1$ at the point $x=R$?

Comment: here $f'(x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{R^2/x^2-1}}$ which goes to infinity as $x$ tends to $0$ so $f'$ is not continuous on $0$